# Call a JSP from a menuitem in a Swing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jsp

I have a `JFrame` here like this..

[image: Jframe]

I've tried using this code in another class
and this menu item I want it to call the .jsp page... I've tried the `ActionListener`, using this code in another class:

```
function openPage() {
  PaginaPrincipal.jsp({
  type : 'POST',
  data : PaginaPrincipal(this).serialize(),
  url : '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/post_action',
  success : function(data, textStatus) {
  PaginaPrincipal('#iframeId').contents().find('body').append(data);
  },
  error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  }
  });
}
```

How can I make it so the page is called and make it "post"?

Comment: You seem to be mixing oil and water here -- Swing and JSP.

Comment: Well yeah kind of... but I'm not trying to call the jsp inside the swing what I'm trying to do is that when you press the menuitem then the jsp starts to work any ideas?? 'cause I'm dumbfound really

Comment: Swing code is executed at client in desktop application, JSP on server (servlet container). Totally different.